# Some discrepancy in python Regex

Tags: python, string, python-3.7

I coded a python regex to find a construct in a file. When i check for groups, the output adds extra string to my output.

I am providing my preliminary problem, on basis of which i have some other dependencies.

```
import re
pattern = reg = r"(.*) \((.*) (.*) (.*) (.*) (.*)\).*NCH.*"
sentence = test = 'MN0 (\4\:y \5\:c1 n0 \3\:vbbpw \3\:vbbpw) NCH 
m=1 '
check = re.match(pattern,sentence)
check.group(0)
```

I expect

```
'MN0 (\4\:y \5\:c1 n0 \3\:vbbpw \3\:vbbpw) NCH m=1 ',
```

but what i end up getting is

```
'MN0 (\x04\\:y \x05\\:c1 n0 \x03\\:vbbpw \x03\\:vbbpw) NCH m=1 '
```

Is there a reson for x0 appended before all the numbers in my input string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that string in `sentence` variable isn't raw string. That means `\4`, `\5` etc. are treated like characters with appropriate ascii codes (`'\x04'`, `'\x05'` ...) . Put `r` before the string:

```
import re
pattern = reg = r"(.*) \((.*) (.*) (.*) (.*) (.*)\).*NCH.*"
sentence = test = r'MN0 (\4\:y \5\:c1 n0 \3\:vbbpw \3\:vbbpw) NCH m=1 '
check = re.match(pattern,sentence)
print(check.group(0))
```

Prints:

```
MN0 (\4\:y \5\:c1 n0 \3\:vbbpw \3\:vbbpw) NCH m=1
```